# Failing to capture mouse position and therefore pixel data

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Reposting question as clearer now.

What I have is a page with x number of images on. What I want to do is be able to click on any part of any image and make that particular color transparent in the image clicked on. `Turning its Alpha to 0`

So, images:

```
<div id="resizeImg" style="width:300px; left:50px;" class="pic">
    <img id="image" src="http://myurl.com/images/3727.jpg" width=300 />
</div>
<div id="resizeImg" style="width:300px; left:50px;" class="pic">
    <img id="image1" src="http://myurl.com/images/3728.jpg" width=300 />
</div>
<div id="resizeImg" style="width:300px; left:50px;" class="pic">
    <img id="image2" src="http://myurl.com/images/3729.jpg" width=300 />
</div>
```

Below is what I'm trying, inspector tells me `ImageData { width=300, height=300, data=Uint8ClampedArray}`

When I click `data=Uint8ClampedArray` to see whats in there the browser (ff) freezes and asks if want to stop script.

So its getting caught in a loop and when I do finally see `data=Uint8ClampedArray it shows 0=255, 1=255, 2=255` even though I clicked something red.

I think the problem is in the capturing the mouse position and the pixel clicked on.

```
// get mouse position

function findPos(obj) {
    var current_left = 0,
        current_top = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            current_left += obj.offsetLeft;
            current_top += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return {
            x: current_left,
            y: current_top
        };
    }
    return undefined;
}

// click
$('[id^=image]').click(function (e) {
    var after = $(this)[0];
    after.src = white2transparent(after);
})

function white2transparent(img) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var w = img.width,
        h = img.height;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;

    // get the position
    var position = findPos(img);
    var x = img.pageX - position.x;
    var y = img.pageY - position.y;
    var coordinate = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;

    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    ctx.width = w;
    ctx.height = h;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

    // show rgb colors in inspector
    console.log(imageData);

    var pixel = imageData.data;

    var r = 0,
        g = 1,
        b = 2,
        a = 3;
    for (var p = 0; p < pixel.length; p += 4) {
        if (
        // this is where I need to return the RGB found and replace 220
        pixel[p + r] >= 220 &&
            pixel[p + g] >= 220 &&
            pixel[p + b] >= 220) {
            pixel[p + a] = 0;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    return c.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

This section is where I need to return the RGB of the clickde pixel and replace the 220 with each of the vealues

```
if (
    // this is where I need to return the RGB found and replace 220
      pixel[p+r] >= 220 &&
      pixel[p+g] >= 220 &&
      pixel[p+b] >= 220)
```

**EDIT**

When I try view co-ordinates in inspector using:

```
// show x + y
console.log("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
```

It returns `x=NaN, y=NaN`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine two functions jquery and JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699691/combine-two-functions-jquery-and-js)

Comment: You should edit your previous question rather than posting a new one that is largely the same problem.

Comment: @AndyE I did edit and some users said better to post new question??

Comment: one option is to delete your previous question, I suppose.

Comment: @AndyE Deleted previous

Comment: @DarrenSweeney nowhere in your code are you checking for the mouse position. What should findPos return?

Comment: @OpherV This should find the position? // get the position
    var position = findPos(img);
    var x = img.pageX - position.x;
    var y = img.pageY - position.y;
    var coordinate = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;

Comment: @DarrenSweeney That function doesn't do what you think it does. it has no reference of the actual click event, which you need to determine the click position. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the mouse position relative to the image, you should use the click event itself like so

```
$('[id^=image]').click(function (e) {
   // an array representing the relative x\y mouse coordinates within the image
   var relativeMousePosition=[e.pageX-$(this).offset().left,e.pageY-$(this).offset().top];

})
```